# issues in calling google drive api access from google app engine for java

Tags: google-app-engine, google-drive-api

i am trying to access google drive docs using the drive api from google app engine. as a start i wrote the servlet to access the authorization code etc with below code:

```
package vik.sakshum.sakshumweb.server.common;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.Credential;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleClientSecrets;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException;
import com.google.api.client.http.HttpTransport;
import com.google.api.client.http.javanet.NetHttpTransport;
import com.google.api.client.json.JsonFactory;
import com.google.api.client.json.jackson.JacksonFactory;
import com.google.api.services.drive.Drive;
import com.google.api.services.oauth2.Oauth2;
import com.google.api.services.oauth2.model.Userinfo;
import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RemoteServiceServlet;

/**
 * Abstract servlet that sets up credentials and provides some convenience
 * methods.
 *
 * @author vicfryzel@google.com (Vic Fryzel)
 * @author jbd@google.com (Burcu Dogan)
 */
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public abstract class GoogleDriveAuth extends RemoteServiceServlet {
  /**
   * Default transportation layer for Google Apis Java client.
   */
  protected static final HttpTransport TRANSPORT = new NetHttpTransport();

  /**
   * Default JSON factory for Google Apis Java client.
   */
  protected static final JsonFactory JSON_FACTORY = new JacksonFactory();

  /**
   * Key to get/set userId from and to the session.
   */
  public static final String KEY_SESSION_USERID = "user_id";

  /**
   * Default MIME type of files created or handled by DrEdit.
   * This is also set in the Google APIs Console under the Drive SDK tab.
   */
  public static final String DEFAULT_MIMETYPE = "text/plain";

  /**
   * Path component under war/ to locate client_secrets.json file.
   */
  public static final String CLIENT_SECRETS_FILE_PATH
      = "/WEB-INF/client_secrets.json";

  /**
   * A credential manager to get, set, delete credential objects.
   */
  private CredentialManager credentialManager = null;

  /**
   * Initializes the Servlet.
   *
  @Override
  public void init() throws ServletException {
    super.init();
    // init credential manager
//    credentialManager = new CredentialManager(
//        getClientSecrets(), TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY);
  }*/

  /**
   * Dumps the given object as JSON and responds with given HTTP status code.
   * @param resp  Response object.
   * @param code  HTTP status code to respond with.
   * @param obj   An object to be dumped as JSON.
   */
  protected void sendJson(HttpServletResponse resp, int code, Object obj) {
    try {
      // TODO(burcud): Initialize Gson instance for once.
      resp.setContentType("application/json");
      resp.getWriter().print(new Gson().toJson(obj).toString());
    } catch (IOException e) {
      throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
  }

  /**
   * Dumps the given object to JSON and responds with HTTP 200.
   * @param resp  Response object.
   * @param obj   An object to be dumped as JSON.
   */
  protected void sendJson(HttpServletResponse resp, Object obj) {
    sendJson(resp, 200, obj);
  }

  /**
   * Responds with the given HTTP status code and message.
   * @param resp  Response object.
   * @param code  HTTP status code to respond with.
   * @param message Message body.
   */
  protected void sendError(HttpServletResponse resp, int code, String message) {
    try {
      resp.sendError(code, message);
    } catch (IOException e) {
      throw new RuntimeException(message);
    }
  }

  /**
   * Transforms a GoogleJsonResponseException to an HTTP response.
   * @param resp  Response object.
   * @param e     Exception object to transform.
   */
  protected void sendGoogleJsonResponseError(HttpServletResponse resp,
      GoogleJsonResponseException e) {
    sendError(resp, e.getStatusCode(), e.getLocalizedMessage());
  }

  /**
   * Redirects to OAuth2 consent page if user is not logged in.
   * @param req   Request object.
   * @param resp  Response object.
   */
  protected void loginIfRequired(HttpServletRequest req,
      HttpServletResponse resp) {
    Credential credential = getCredential(req, resp);
    if (credential == null) {
      // redirect to authorization url
      try {
        resp.sendRedirect(credentialManager.getAuthorizationUrl());
      } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Can't redirect to auth page");
      }
    }
  }

  /**
   * If OAuth2 redirect callback is invoked and there is a code query param,
   * retrieve user credentials and profile. Then, redirect to the home page.
   * @param req   Request object.
   * @param resp  Response object.
   * @throws IOException
   */
  protected void handleCallbackIfRequired(HttpServletRequest req,
      HttpServletResponse resp) throws IOException {
    String code = req.getParameter("code");
    System.out.println("Code is:" + code);
    if (code != null) {
      // retrieve new credentials with code
      Credential credential = credentialManager.retrieve(code);
      // request userinfo
      Oauth2 service = getOauth2Service(credential);
      try {
        Userinfo about = service.userinfo().get().execute();
        String id = about.getId();
        credentialManager.save(id, credential);
        req.getSession().setAttribute(KEY_SESSION_USERID, id);

        System.out.println("vik:: accessToken:" + credential.getAccessToken() + " refreshToken:" + credential.getRefreshToken());
      } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Can't handle the OAuth2 callback, " + 
            "make sure that code is valid.");
      }
      resp.sendRedirect("/");
    }
  }

  @Override
  public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
      throws IOException, ServletException {
      System.out.println("start of GoogleDriveAuth:::::::");
      credentialManager = new CredentialManager(
                getClientSecrets(), TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY);
      handleCallbackIfRequired(req, resp);
  }

  /**
   * Returns the credentials of the user in the session. If user is not in the
   * session, returns null.
   * @param req   Request object.
   * @param resp  Response object.
   * @return      Credential object of the user in session or null.
   */
  protected Credential getCredential(HttpServletRequest req,
      HttpServletResponse resp) {
    String userId = (String) req.getSession().getAttribute(KEY_SESSION_USERID);
    if (userId != null) {
      return credentialManager.get(userId);
    }
    return null;
  }

  /**
   * Deletes the credentials of the user in the session permanently and removes
   * the user from the session.
   * @param req   Request object.
   * @param resp  Response object.
   */
  protected void deleteCredential(HttpServletRequest req,
      HttpServletResponse resp) {
    String userId = (String) req.getSession().getAttribute(KEY_SESSION_USERID);
    if (userId != null) {
      credentialManager.delete(userId);
      req.getSession().removeAttribute(KEY_SESSION_USERID);
    }
  }

  /**
   * Build and return a Drive service object based on given request parameters.
   * @param credential User credentials.
   * @return Drive service object that is ready to make requests, or null if
   *         there was a problem.
   */
  protected Drive getDriveService(Credential credential) {
    return new Drive.Builder(TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY, credential).build();
  }

  /**
   * Build and return an Oauth2 service object based on given request parameters.
   * @param credential User credentials.
   * @return Drive service object that is ready to make requests, or null if
   *         there was a problem.
   */
  protected Oauth2 getOauth2Service(Credential credential) {
    return new Oauth2.Builder(TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY, credential).build();
  }

  /**
   * Reads client_secrets.json and creates a GoogleClientSecrets object.
   * @return A GoogleClientsSecrets object.
   */
  private GoogleClientSecrets getClientSecrets() {
    // TODO: do not read on each request
    InputStream stream =
        getServletContext().getResourceAsStream(CLIENT_SECRETS_FILE_PATH);
    try {
      return GoogleClientSecrets.load(JSON_FACTORY, stream);
    } catch (IOException e) {
      throw new RuntimeException("No client_secrets.json found");
    }
  }
}
```

on invoking the servlet I see following error in the logs:

```
javax.servlet.ServletContext log: unavailable
java.lang.InstantiationException
    at sun.reflect.InstantiationExceptionConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(InstantiationExceptionConstructorAccessorImpl.java:48)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:525)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Class.java:370)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:323)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Holder.newInstance(Holder.java:153)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.initServlet(ServletHolder.java:428)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.getServlet(ServletHolder.java:339)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:487)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1166)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.appstats.AppstatsFilter.doFilter(AppstatsFilter.java:141)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.ParseBlobUploadFilter.doFilter(ParseBlobUploadFilter.java:125)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.SaveSessionFilter.doFilter(SaveSessionFilter.java:35)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.JdbcMySqlConnectionCleanupFilter.doFilter(JdbcMySqlConnectionCleanupFilter.java:57)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.TransactionCleanupFilter.doFilter(TransactionCleanupFilter.java:43)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:388)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:765)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:418)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.AppVersionHandlerMap.handle(AppVersionHandlerMap.java:266)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:326)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:542)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(HttpConnection.java:923)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.RpcRequestParser.parseAvailable(RpcRequestParser.java:76)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:404)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.JettyServletEngineAdapter.serviceRequest(JettyServletEngineAdapter.java:146)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.JavaRuntime$RequestRunnable.run(JavaRuntime.java:439)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.runInContext(TraceContext.java:483)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable$1.run(TraceContext.java:490)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext.runInContext(TraceContext.java:777)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$DoInTraceContext.runInContext(TraceContext.java:754)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContextNoUnref(TraceContext.java:345)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContext(TraceContext.java:337)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.run(TraceContext.java:487)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.ThreadGroupPool$PoolEntry.run(ThreadGroupPool.java:251)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
W2013-06-18 18:26:57.398
/GoogleOauth
java.lang.InstantiationException
    at sun.reflect.InstantiationExceptionConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(InstantiationExceptionConstructorAccessorImpl.java:48)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:525)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Class.java:370)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:323)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Holder.newInstance(Holder.java:153)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.initServlet(ServletHolder.java:428)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.getServlet(ServletHolder.java:339)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:487)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1166)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.appstats.AppstatsFilter.doFilter(AppstatsFilter.java:141)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.ParseBlobUploadFilter.doFilter(ParseBlobUploadFilter.java:125)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.SaveSessionFilter.doFilter(SaveSessionFilter.java:35)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.JdbcMySqlConnectionCleanupFilter.doFilter(JdbcMySqlConnectionCleanupFilter.java:57)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.TransactionCleanupFilter.doFilter(TransactionCleanupFilter.java:43)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:388)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:765)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:418)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.AppVersionHandlerMap.handle(AppVersionHandlerMap.java:266)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:326)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:542)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(HttpConnection.java:923)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.RpcRequestParser.parseAvailable(RpcRequestParser.java:76)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:404)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.JettyServletEngineAdapter.serviceRequest(JettyServletEngineAdapter.java:146)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.JavaRuntime$RequestRunnable.run(JavaRuntime.java:439)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.runInContext(TraceContext.java:483)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable$1.run(TraceContext.java:490)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext.runInContext(TraceContext.java:777)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$DoInTraceContext.runInContext(TraceContext.java:754)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContextNoUnref(TraceContext.java:345)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContext(TraceContext.java:337)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.run(TraceContext.java:487)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.ThreadGroupPool$PoolEntry.run(ThreadGroupPool.java:251)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
C2013-06-18 18:26:57.478
Uncaught exception from servlet
java.lang.InstantiationException
    at sun.reflect.InstantiationExceptionConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(InstantiationExceptionConstructorAccessorImpl.java:48)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:525)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Class.java:370)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:323)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Holder.newInstance(Holder.java:153)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.initServlet(ServletHolder.java:428)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.getServlet(ServletHolder.java:339)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:487)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1166)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.appstats.AppstatsFilter.doFilter(AppstatsFilter.java:141)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.ParseBlobUploadFilter.doFilter(ParseBlobUploadFilter.java:125)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.SaveSessionFilter.doFilter(SaveSessionFilter.java:35)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.JdbcMySqlConnectionCleanupFilter.doFilter(JdbcMySqlConnectionCleanupFilter.java:57)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.TransactionCleanupFilter.doFilter(TransactionCleanupFilter.java:43)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:388)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:765)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:418)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.AppVersionHandlerMap.handle(AppVersionHandlerMap.java:266)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:326)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:542)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(HttpConnection.java:923)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.RpcRequestParser.parseAvailable(RpcRequestParser.java:76)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:404)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.JettyServletEngineAdapter.serviceRequest(JettyServletEngineAdapter.java:146)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.JavaRuntime$RequestRunnable.run(JavaRuntime.java:439)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.runInContext(TraceContext.java:483)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable$1.run(TraceContext.java:490)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext.runInContext(TraceContext.java:777)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$DoInTraceContext.runInContext(TraceContext.java:754)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContextNoUnref(TraceContext.java:345)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContext(TraceContext.java:337)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.run(TraceContext.java:487)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.ThreadGroupPool$PoolEntry.run(ThreadGroupPool.java:251)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

Comment: I can't say what's wrong, but start with this : https://developers.google.com/drive/examples/java After you get that sample working start to copy more and more code from sample to your project until you get it working.

Comment: i copied the code from there only and banging my head why it doesnt work. another problem is that my case is different where i am trying to invoke the code on app engine which is a little different environment so not sure even if this code works as a regular web app will still work on GAE

Comment: then i would bet on wrong version of your libraries. Update your maven dependencies and if you are not using Maven juste all your libraries. Does untouched DrEdit App (without any modifications) works for you ?

Comment: sorry i was editing my original response during the time you were responding. plz re-read my above comment

Comment: found first issue as drive sdk was not enabled. so enabling and retrying

Comment: same error so making progress with DrEdit to see if i find more missing stuff

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the issue was abstract keyword in the class name. I removed it and it fixed. So a typical copy paste error.